# Firewalld Configuration on Centos 7.2

Tags: mongodb, centos7, robo3t, firewalld

I have installed **MongoDB** on my **CentOS 7.2** VPS and trying to access to the DB via Robomongo from my client. However, when I try to connect the server from the **27017** port, I get "**Network is unreachable**" error.

I have enabled the **firewalld** on the server and added an exception for **27017** port.

```
firewall-cmd --list-all
```

Result:

[image: Result:]

*I got this result after I've permanently added the exception and reloaded the firewalld via --reload.*

When I query the port by using:

```
firewall-cmd --query-port=27017/tcp
```

I get a "**yes**" from the system. However when I try to connect via Robomongo or query the port via a port checker service like http://ping.eu/port-chk/ I get a negative result.

Do you have any suggestions regarding to my case?

Thank you.

Comment: what IP is used by mongd process?

Comment: Local Address: 127.0.0.1:27017
Foreign Address: 0.0.0.0:*

Comment: Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with the help of the VPS support team via performing the steps below:

Execute,

```
ss -plnt
```

to see the **socket statistics**. My output was like below:

[image: Socket Statistics]

As can be seen from the result **mongod** process is listening **27017** port **only on 127.0.0.1** . In order to configure that binding edit the **mongod.conf** in **/etc/** directory and comment out the line

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

Restart the mongodb service and everything should be fine.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue, but running mongod in a Centos 7 Vm.

First i had to open the mongodb port with firewall-cmd:

```
 sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=27017/tcp --permanent

 sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Then i had to change the net Configuration entry in /etc/mongodb.conf
See also : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net-options

I removed the bindIp: Entry and added bindIpAll: true

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIpAll: true
```

Using bindIp: according the documentation you need to enter:

*The IP addresses and/or full Unix domain socket paths on which mongos and mongod should listen for client connections. You may attach mongos and mongod to any interface. To bind to multiple addresses, enter a list of comma-separated values*

The default is:

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

which means that mongodb only listens to localhost